# Does everything have to be original?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, challenges

Many [kolmogorov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov) challenges are closed as duplicates of the [Rickroll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6043/31516) challenge. [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) challenges are closed as duplicates of various other challenges that are somewhat similar. [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges are closed as duplicates of challenges that [touch the same concepts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/optimal-path-through-a-matrix#comment342259_139463) as other challenges.

The question rate has dropped, and there are fewer new challenges now, than a few years ago. This is not strange, since it's getting harder and harder to come up with original ideas. I think it's safe to say that most people are more interested in answering new challenges than older ones<sup>1</sup>.

---

So, is it really a problem if a question is similar to another one?

- Why can't we have ASCII-art challenges that are somewhat similar to another one?
- Why can't we have Kolmorogov challenges that are somewhat similar to another one?
- Why can't we have code-golf challenges that are somewhat similar to another one?

I guess the answers to this question will be one of the two below. I'm curios to see which one attracts the most votes.

> I'm quite tired of this general attitude that nothing is a duplicate because of minor differences in the approach of language X.

and

> I'm quite tired of people spoiling challenges because of faint similarities.

Note: This is a *question*, not an opinion, so a vote on the question doesn't show which side you're on. Please up/downvote the *answers* you agree/disagree with.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Maybe not you, but I'm generalizing here.</sub>

Comment: I personally think it's somewhat in the middle. Some _ASCII-art_ or _kolmogorov-complexity_ challenges are too similar to existing ones. Although the approach might be different for some languages, sometimes 75% can almost copy-paste the answer of the previous challenge to port it to the new one. In that case I think a duplicated-vote is in order. In other cases another challenge might look similar at first, but the answers are completely different in the majority of the languages posted. In that case it shouldn't be closed as a dupe. The problem is; how to determine this beforehand?

Comment: @PeterTaylor does every meta post have to be original? On a more serious note: I'm not sure I agree with your statement that good questions get buried. We get 2-4 questions each day. And I'm not talking about allowing everything, I'm talking about allowing a few more questions that share some of the same concepts as others.

Comment: It's a bit ironic to close this as a duplicate :P

Comment: If the old one is Close, one, for me could propose the same question. If it is not close, for me, seen the wrong precision of the downvoters + duplicate vote enthusiast , duplicate has to never exist.

Comment: Meta-duplicate. XD